# Save onclick attribute value in a variable and then execute it

Tags: jquery

I have some `input`s (buttons). Their `onclick` function is added programmatically. I'd like to take their `onclick` function and to put it in a variable and do some function instead and then execute whatever it was in their `onclick`.

So far I managed to get their `onclick` function and put it in a variable and execute my code but now I have no idea how to execute the old `onclick` function that is in this variable.

```
var example = $(item).attr('onclick');
//do other stuff
```

P.S  For some reason I can't use a pre-function to delay this `onclick` function from executing until my function is finished so I need my `onclick` function to save somewhere like the code above and then launch.

Comment: `onclick` attribute has String value, which you can execute using `eval()`. [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kekL1d1d/1/).

Comment: @sara.y please add your code/ jsfiddle here, what you tried?

Comment: _onclick function is made programmatically_ How you are doing it? Can you show the code

Comment: @regent : thanks it works perfectly....I write the code so it may answer someone else question too.. eval(example);

Comment: @sara.y you're welcome. If your problem is solved, either you can remove the question or I can post this as an answer, if you are ready to accept it.

Comment: I think if you post it as an answer is better...it's a very simple question but it may help someone else as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` attribute has `String` value which you have saved in variable.
You can execute it as code using [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kekL1d1d/1/).

```
<div onclick="test();">test</div>

function test()
{
    alert(1);
}

$(function()
{
    eval($('div').attr('onclick'));
});
```